# Implementar toastr en mi formulario de contacto

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Cómo puedo implementar el [Toastr JS](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) en mi formulario de contacto. Quiero que salga `toastr.success` y `toastr.error` en vez de los `alert()` que tengo ahora.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "info@micorreo.com";
$email_subject = "Mensaje de Mi Dominio";

if(!isset($_POST['nombre']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['mensaje'])) {

echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['nombre'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . "\n\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo '<script languaje="javascript">
                alert("Mensaje Enviado");
            location.href="midominio.com";
            </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script languaje="javascript">
            alert("Mensaje No Enviado");
            location.href="midominio.com";
            </script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:
Lo puedes ver en [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jx1f4grL/).

**Html**

```
<input type="button" value="Error" id="error" />
<input type="button" value="Info" id="info" />
<input type="button" value="Warning" id="warning" />
<input type="button" value="Success" id="success" />
<br><br><br><br>
```

**jQuery:**
Necesitas incluir las librerías, ver resources en el enlace del fiddle

```
$(function () {
    $('#error').click(function () {
        // make it not dissappear
        toastr.error("Noooo oo oo ooooo!!!", "Title", {
            "timeOut": "0",
            "extendedTImeout": "0"
        });
    });
    $('#info').click(function () {
        // title is optional
        toastr.info("Info Message", "Title");
    });
    $('#warning').click(function () {
        toastr.warning("Warning");
    });
    $('#success').click(function () {
        toastr.success("YYEESSSSSSS");
    });
});
```

Ejemplo oficial:     http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir los estilos css y js de tostr en el head de tu sitio (importante incluir JQuery antes del archivo JS de tostr ya que necesita de JQuery para funcionar), luego dentro de los echo puedes hacer el llamado a la libreria con el texto que desees y opcionalmente también le puedes incluir titulo y [opciones](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html).

Ejemplo básico

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Hoja de estilos Toastr -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
  <!-- JQuery Primero -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Toastr.js Después -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
  <title>Toaster</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Toaster</h1>
  <?php

  // Poner en false para que se ejecute el else.
  $foo = true;

  if ($foo) {
    echo '<script>
    toastr.success("Mensaje Enviado");
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.href = "https://www.example.com";
    }, 3000);
  </script>';
  } else {
    echo '<script>
    toastr.error("Mensaje No Enviado", "Error");
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.href = "https://www.example.com";
    }, 3000);
    </script>';
  }

  ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Saludos.